# Selenium IDE: I cant check a special checkbox dynamically

Tags: selenium-ide

I use a special multiselect with checkboxes and i want to select a checkbox dynamically with an index.Note that those option are checkboxes and the code above is hidden.
For now, selenium does a :        click     //input[@value='6'] but its not dynamic for me since those value will change when we update a version of our system!This makes me edit selenium each time we need to do tests wich is useless since i use more time editing the targets than testing

```
<select id="multiselect_category" class="form-control" style="display: none;" multiple="multiple" title="Catégorie(s)" name="category_selection[]">
    <option value="150"></option>
    <option value="160"></option>
    <option value="174"></option>
    <option value="175"></option>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="category_selection[]"></input>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how it was working! I just used the input(not hidden instead of the select(hidden) and i added a specific class to the form group just to identify it.
Then:   xpath=(//div[@class='form-group group_multiselect_category_selection']/div/div/div/ul/li[3]//input[1])    was the right xpath to use.

```
<div class="form-group group_multiselect_project_selection">

    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select id="multiselect_project" class="form-control" style="display: none;" multiple="multiple" title="Projet(s)" name="project_selection[]"></select>
            <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%;">
                <button class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" style="width: 100%;" title="Aucune de sélectionné"></button>
                <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                    <li class="multiselect-item filter" value="0"></li>
                    <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all"></li>
                    <li></li>
```